# Data from a WordPress custom plugin form is not inserted into the MySQL database

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have tried to create a custom plugin where when the user activate the plugin the table is automatically created in the database and when deactivate the table will also be deleted. The table is created but when the user fill the form and click on submit the user data is not inserting into the database.

** Fist Code File **

```
<?php
/*

 * Plugin Name:       NFTP Get Quote
 * Plugin URI:        https://example.com/plugins/the-basics/
 * Description:       Handle the basics with this plugin.
 * Version:           1.10.3
 * Requires at least: 5.2
 * Requires PHP:      7.2
 * Author:            Isha Bhutto
 * Author URI:        https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01a72e9e83e6dd47a2
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Update URI:        https://example.com/my-plugin/
 * Text Domain:       nftp_get_quote
 * Domain Path:       /languages

 */

if (function_exists('ngq_get_quote_form')) {


} else {


    function ngq_get_quote_form()
    {


        $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
            <title>Get a Quote</title>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="form-container">
                <h2>Get a Quote</h2>
                <form action="<?php echo plugins_url('form_submittion.php', __FILE__); ?>" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="current_path" value="<?php echo $actual_link; ?>">
                    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>

                    <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>

                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="4" required></textarea>

                    <button type="submit" name="quote-submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>

        </html>

        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();

    }
}



add_shortcode("nftp_get_quote_form", "ngq_get_quote_form");

// ADD CSS FILE

function utm_user_scripts()
{
    $plugin_url = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);

    wp_enqueue_style('nftp_get_quote', $plugin_url . "style.css");
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'utm_user_scripts');


// ADD HOOKS

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'deactivate');



function activate()
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $table_prefix;
    $table = $table_prefix . 'quotetable';

    // check to see if the table exists already, if not, then create it.

    if ($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$table'") != $table) {

        $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE $table (
            `sno` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
            `msg` text NOT NULL
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;";


        $sql2 = "ALTER TABLE $table 
        ADD PRIMARY KEY (`sno`);";

        $sql3 = "ALTER TABLE $table 
        MODIFY `sno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;";

        $wpdb->query($sql1);
        $wpdb->query($sql2);
        $wpdb->query($sql3);

    }

}

function deactivate()
{

    global $wpdb;
    global $table_prefix;
    $table = $table_prefix . 'quotetable';

    $sql = "DROP TABLE $table";

    $wpdb->query($sql);

}



?>
```

** Second Code File **

```
<?php 

require ('../../../wp-load.php');

        global $wpdb;
        global $table_prefix;
        $table = $table_prefix . 'quotetable';

      

        if (isset($_POST['quote-submit'])) {

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $msg = $_POST['message'];

            $wpdb->insert($table, Array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'message' => $msg));

            $current_path = $_POST['current_path'];


            ?>
            <script>
                window.location = '<?php  echo $current_path;?>';
            </script>
            <?php    

        }
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The data is not inserting from this code to the mysql database. Like i have created a form where user enters his name , email and description so when the user click on submit button the data should be stored into the database. but it isnt! i dont undnerstand the problem in my code.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. That's so little code that even vardump could help to spot where it is going wrong. Also, is there any good reason to write a PHP redirect using JS?